# Keep custom QAbstractItemModel alive for the life of a QMainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, static, qt5

I have two custom models that I would like to keep alive for the life of my main window.  Both are built from the Qt sample http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html of a custom tree model.

These are models that contain a hierarchy of folders/directories named "local" and "remote".

Can I instantiate these in such a way that I can reference them in other member functions of the main window?  How/Can I make them static to the MainWindow, or is there a better way?

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Generate models.
    TreeModel *model_remote = new TreeModel(MainWindow::load_file_list());
    TreeModel *model_local = new TreeModel(localDirList);

    // Display models in a QTreeView.
    ui->treeView_remote->setModel(model_remote);
    ui->treeView_local->setModel(model_local);
}

void MainWindow::some_function()
{
    // Here is where I would like to work with my model(s).
}
```

Comment: ui->treeView_remote->model() is a pointer to your model. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#model

Comment: Or as an alternative, you can also make it a member variable of your MainWindow class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per drescherjm's comment above:

```
ui->treeView_remote->model()
```

is a pointer to the model.